# Basic data formatting in python

Tags: python

I want to format a text file with 7000 entries and use the following code to sort things. But for the last couple of weeks, I am stuck with a problem: 
(input data is as following)

USER_PROTEIN_ID = P25358

SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|P25358|ELO2_YEAST

NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=8

DOMAIN=Pfam:ELO

START=63

END=307

EVALUE=2.4e-64

TYPE=PFAM

**Code.py**

```
file=open('r.txt').readlines()

for line in file:
    line= line.rstrip()
    if re.search('USER|DOMAIN|STATUS=visible|OK', line):
         line= re.sub(r'USER_PROTEIN_ID = |DOMAIN=Pfam:|\s','', line)
         print(''.join(line))
```

What I am getting is:

```
P53242
Vac_ImportDeg
STATUS=visible|OK
P40850
DOMAIN=XPGN
STATUS=visible|OK
XPG_N
DOMAIN=XPGI
STATUS=visible|OK
XPG_I
MKT1_N
STATUS=visible|OK
MKT1_C
STATUS=visible|OK
```

But I wanted to print results started with early line with entry (eg P53242) in sep=\t in following shape:

```
P53242 Vac_ImportDeg STATUS=visible|OK

P40850 DOMAIN=XPGN STATUS=visible|OK XPG_N DOMAIN=XPGI STATUS=visible|OK XPG_I MKT1_N
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the input file?

Comment: I hope that helps, by the way, you're not going to get more help unless you post the input that gave you that output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @AaronHall, following in the input data:

USER_PROTEIN_ID = P25358
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|P25358|ELO2_YEAST
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=8

DOMAIN=Pfam:ELO
START=63
END=307
EVALUE=2.4e-64
TYPE=PFAM

Comment: @user3698773 in the future, please edit the question and add the contents of the file there instead of in a comment.

Comment: It is good to indicate that your issue is solved by accepting an answer that was useful. @user3698773

Answer (score 2):

Without a content file.

Use:

```
print re.sub(r'(P\d+)',r'\n\1 ',re.sub(r'\n','',line))
```

Instead of:

```
print(''.join(line))
```

Comment: Thank you @Klashxx, but it seems the problem is still persists. I am not getting results in this form that is not very useful either:

P38273 
DUF1712
STATUS=visible|OK

P40462 
Peptidase_M1
STATUS=visible|OK

Comment: What is it about that form that is undesirable? I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Does it have to do with removing newlines and/or replacing them with tabs? Or is there some other problem?

Comment: @DaveYarwood, trouble is to join lines after the entry (egP53242) before the next entry (ie P40850) and then separate values in the line with '\t', is it understandable??

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the actual input file (formatted, with newlines intact), but it looks like what you're trying to do is take an input file where entries can span multiple lines, and print it out in a format where each entry is on its own line and the values are separated by tabs.

The problem here is that you are going through the input line by line -- you're using `readlines()`, which returns a list of lines, and then iterating through it line by line with your loop `for line in file:`. This won't work because you have to read multiple lines at a time in order to get one entry.

I would propose getting rid of the `for line in file:` loop and just reading in all of the contents of the file at once, then parsing it down from there. Also, remember that whenever you `open()` a file, you have to `close()` it after you're done with it. The best way to do this is with a context manager (see the `with open(...` line below):

```
import re

with open("r.txt") as f:
    # store the contents of the entire file as a string
    data = f.read()

    # split the string up into a list (tuple) of entries defined by 
    # some regex pattern that looks for the entry name (i.e. P####)
    re_pattern = r"(good luck writing this regex pattern!)+"
    entries = re.match(re_pattern, data).groups()

    # for each entry, substitute tabs for spaces and print the result
    for entry in entries:
        print re.sub(r"\s+", "\t", entry.rstrip())
```

Now the only problem you would need to solve would be writing a regex pattern that can tell one entry from the next, which is actually quite complicate and would involve "negative lookahead." To be honest, I can't figure out how to use negative lookahead properly :) If you're interested, see the python docs on the re module, which include [some very helpful information about regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Given the complex nature of this problem, I would actually recommend using a parsing library (Python has [about 3 billion of them](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing)) in order to make things easier on yourself.

Hope that helps... this task is trickier than it seems!